# Making new strings with array data

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, prototype

I am trying to solve this problem where if age > 18 it returns name + can go to the matrix or if age < 18 returns they are under age:

```
function makeStrings(arr){
  // your code here
}

console.log(makeStrings([
    {
        name: "Angelina Jolie",
        age: 80
    },
    {
        name: "Eric Jones",
        age: 2
    },
    {
        name: "Paris Hilton",
        age: 5
    },
    {
        name: "Kayne West",
        age: 16
    },
    {
        name: "Bob Ziroll",
        age: 100
    }
])); 
// ["Angelina Jolie can go to The Matrix", 
// "Eric Jones is under age!!", 
// "Paris Hilton is under age!!", 
// "Kayne West is under age!!", 
// "Bob Ziroll can go to The Matrix"]
```

The exercise is from a list of array.prototype.map() exercises so although I think there are other ways to get the correct answer I've tried to use the map() method. So far all I've managed to get back is a syntax error or [undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined] which is what the code below returns.

```
function makeStrings(arr){
  // your code here
  const map1 = arr.map((person) => {
    if(person.age > 18){
      person.name + " can go to The Matrix";
    }
    else {
      person.name + "is underage!!";
    }
  });
  return map1;
}

console.log(makeStrings([
    {
        name: "Angelina Jolie",
        age: 80
    },
    {
        name: "Eric Jones",
        age: 2
    },
    {
        name: "Paris Hilton",
        age: 5
    },
    {
        name: "Kayne West",
        age: 16
    },
    {
        name: "Bob Ziroll",
        age: 100
    }
])); 
// ["Angelina Jolie can go to The Matrix", 
// "Eric Jones is under age!!", 
// "Paris Hilton is under age!!", 
// "Kayne West is under age!!", 
// "Bob Ziroll can go to The Matrix"]
```

Comment: Hi, try add return statement like this:
`return person.name + " can go to The Matrix";`

`return person.name + "is underage!!";`

Comment: You can even make function `makeStrings` simplier

`function makeStrings(arr) {
  return arr.map((person) => {
    if (person.age > 18) {
      return person.name + " can go to The Matrix";
    }
    return person.name + "is underage!!";
  });
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
function makeStrings(arr) {
  const result = [];

  for (const person of arr) {
    if (person.age >= 18) {
      result.push(`${person.name} can go to The Matrix`);
    } else {
      result.push(`${person.name} is under age!!`);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(makeStrings([
    {
        name: "Angelina Jolie",
        age: 80
    },
    {
        name: "Eric Jones",
        age: 2
    },
    {
        name: "Paris Hilton",
        age: 5
    },
    {
        name: "Kayne West",
        age: 16
    },
    {
        name: "Bob Ziroll",
        age: 100
    }
]));
```

you should try

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).